# Multiple <a target=" "> attributes?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page with a Google Tour in an iframe. I've set iframe's name as "vtour". The iframe is inside a div whose ID I've set to "tour".

Below the iframe I have some links that jump to certain locations in the Google Tour (within the iframe). This works fine, except that now only the bottom bit of the iframe is on screen since I've scrolled down the page somewhat in order to access the links below it. So I would like these links to jump me higher up on the page by targeting the div's ID so the full iframe is in view.

Is it possible to have a link target both the content inside an iframe and the iframe's location on the page using the div ID? Or, since my iframe is near the top of the page, the target attribute "_top" could also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the target attribute can only point to one target browsing context at a time. You'll probably need to use a JavaScript click handler to scroll the page programmatically as the link navigates the iframe.